# The CLR type does not exist or you do not have permission to access it

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

Working in Visual Studio 2010.  I have a query which works fine when executed from SQL Server Management Studio, but which keeps throwing this error:

*SQL Execution Error
Executed SQL Statement: ...
Error Source: .Net SqlClientData Provider
Error Message: Parameter 3 ([dbName].[].[unknown]): The CLR type does not exist or you do not have permissions to access it.*

whenever I attempt to run the query in Visual Studio (SSRS) query designer.

The query selects a number of fields from several tables in the subquery, then computes some aggregate values in the outer query.  I deleted the dataset and rebuilt it but am still getting the same error.

I've tracked it down to the two lines:
   CASE WHEN R.ClosingDate >= @StartDate AND CS.ClosingStatus = 'Family Intact' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Period_InTact
   CASE WHEN R.ClosingDate >= @StartDate AND CR.ClosingReason = 'Withdrawn' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Period_Withdrawn
which function properly if I hard code a date in place of @StartDate.

Would appreciate suggestions.

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN T.Period_Intact = 1 AND Age >= 0 AND Age < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Period_Intact_Zero_to_Six
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.YTD_Intact  = 1 AND Age >= 0 AND Age < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_Intact_Zero_to_Six
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Period_Intact = 1  AND Age > 6 AND Age < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Period_Intact_Seven_to_18
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.YTD_Intact = 1  AND Age > 6 AND Age < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_Intact_Seven_to_18
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Period_Withdrawn = 1  AND Age >= 0 AND Age < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Period_Intact_Zero_to_Six
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.YTD_Withdrawn = 1  AND Age >= 0 AND Age < 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_Intact_Zero_to_Six
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Period_Withdrawn = 1  AND Age > 6 AND Age < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Period_Intact_Seven_to_18
, SUM(CASE WHEN T.YTD_Withdrawn = 1  AND Age > 6 AND Age < 19 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS YTD_Intact_Seven_to_18

FROM (

    SELECT R.ProgramID, R.CountyID, R.ReferralName, R.ReferralID
, Cast(R.ReferralDate as date) as ReferralDate, Cast(R.ClosingDate as date) as ClosingDate
, RCND.FirstName, RCND.LastName
, CASE WHEN RCND.DOB IS NULL THEN -1
   WHEN R.ClosingDate IS NULL then -1
   ELSE Datediff(year, RCND.DOB, R.ClosingDate) - CASE WHEN datefromparts(Year(getdate()), Month(R.ClosingDate), Day(R.ClosingDate)) <= datefromparts(Year(getdate()), Month(RCND.DOB), Day(RCND.DOB)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
   END as Age
, R.ClosingReasonID, CR.ClosingReason 
, R.ClosingStatusID, IsNull(CS.ClosingStatus, '') as ClosingStatus

, CASE WHEN R.ClosingDate >= @StartDate AND CS.ClosingStatus = 'Family Intact' THEN 1 Else 0 END as Period_InTact
, CASE WHEN CS.ClosingStatus = 'Family Intact' THEN 1 Else 0 END as YTD_InTact
, CASE WHEN R.ClosingDate >= @StartDate AND CR.ClosingReason = 'Withdrawn' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as Period_Withdrawn
, CASE WHEN CR.ClosingReason = 'Withdrawn' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as YTD_Withdrawn

FROM tblFPReferrals AS R LEFT JOIN
     tblFPClosingReasons AS CR ON R.ClosingReasonID = CR.ClosingReasonID LEFT JOIN
     tblFPClosingStatuses as CS on R.ClosingStatusID = CS.ClosingStatusID LEFT JOIN 
     dbo.vw_Referral_Children_Names_and_DOB as RCND ON R.ReferralID = RCND.ReferralID
WHERE (R.ProgramID = @ProgramID)
AND (R.CountyID = @CountyID)
AND (R.ReferralDate < DateAdd(day, 1, @EndDate))
AND R.ClosingDate >= Cast(cast(Year(@EndDate) + (case when Month(@EndDate) >= 10 then 0 else -1 end) as nvarchar) + '-10-01' as date)
AND R.ClosingDate < Dateadd(day, 1, @EndDate)
) AS T
```

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the same data source with the same credentials as you did in SSMS? Also, when you added the data source in SSRS, did you test the connection to make sure that works?

Comment: Steven, yes, the DataSource works fine.  I've got 4 other queries in the report that are using the same datasource and run just fine.  I rechecked all of the parameters for the report and they are all declared with the correct data type, but for some reason, @StartDate is not being recognized as a date in VS query designer.